# ASP Identity 2 + Web API Token Auth - Persistent claims not Loading

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Im having some trouble with claims in ASP.NET Web API Token Auth.

Essentially I have created a user with some claims (values are being stored in the AspNetUserClaim table) but when the users identity is created, those claims are not being pulled from the database.

A breakdown of my setup is as follows.

1. User Class: Has a GenerateUserIdentityAsync method (pretty standard) and a couple of custom properties:

   ```
   public class LibraryUser : IdentityUser{
       //Add Custom Properties Here
       public string Company { get; set; }

       public string DisplayName { get; set; }

       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<LibraryUser> manager, string authenticationType)
       {
           // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

           // Add custom user claims here
           return userIdentity;
       }
   }
   ```
2. My DBContext declares some simple name changes to make the DB look nicer

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

       // Modify the Model creation properties..
       modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

       //Rename Identity 2.0 Tables to something nicer..
       modelBuilder.Entity<LibraryUser>().ToTable("LibraryUser");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("LibraryUser");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
   }
   ```
3. I have a Simple UserManager class called LibraryUserManager which just extends UserManager for my user Type.

   ```
   public class LibraryUserManager : UserManager<LibraryUser>
   ```
4. When the database is seeded (when calling Update-Database) the following user is created:

   ```
   // -- Create Admin User, put in admin role..
   LibraryUserManager userManager = new LibraryUserManager(new UserStore<LibraryUser>(context));

   var user = new LibraryUser()
   {
       UserName = "admin@admin.com",
       Email = "admin@admin.com",
       DisplayName = "Administrator",
       Company = "Test"
   };

   userManager.Create(user, "Password1.");

   userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
   userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "author"));
   userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "reviewer"));
   userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
   ```
5. Once this is run.. the database has the user (in the LibraryUser table) and the Claims (in the UserClaim table)

[image]

[image]

6. When the user is being authenticated by my custom Auth Provider they are found (via the user manager) and the GenerateUserIdentityAsync is called:

EDIT : showing rest of that method...

```
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<LibraryUserManager>();

    LibraryUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    //check if a user exists
    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, user.DisplayName, oAuthIdentity);           
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

    context.Validated(ticket);
```

7. Contents of create properties (called above):

   ```
   public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, string displayName, ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity)
   {
       IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
           { "userName", userName },
           { "displayName", displayName },
           { "roles", string.Join(",", oAuthIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).ToArray())}
       };

       return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
   }
   ```
8. When the user is authed.. I have put a breakpoint in LibraryUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync (code under point 1 above) and the only claims in the ClaimsIdentity.Claims collection returned by CreateIdentityAsync are the default ones (name, identity_provider, security_stamp and one other..) .. the claims I have manually added are not returned from the DB..

Can anyone see what I am missing??

I have tried to give all the info I can if you require more please comment and I will amend my question.

Thanks in advance :D

_L

Comment: What is the value of the property manager.SupportsUserClaim when you call manager.CreateIdentityAsync()?

Comment: @AugustoBarreto thanks for taking a look. manager.SupportUserClaim is set to true (default).

Comment: @AugustoBarreto after taking a look at some other values in the debugger, I can see that the claims aren't loaded for the user.. lazy loading is turned on though... not sure...

Comment: I don't have lazy loading enabled for my context and still CreateIdentityAsync loads the claims from the db. It's strange because I'm testing with a code very similar to yours. What do you get from calling manager.GetClaims(this.Id)? Also, try using Sql Profiler while calling it to see the executed query and parameters.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto - I called manager.GetClaims(this.Id).. it returned nothing.. my UserClaim table has that weird extra column on the end for some reason.. does your have anything like that?

Comment: Oh right. I missed it. Maybe there is the problem. Mine has 4 columns: Id, UserId, ClaimType and ClaimValue.

Comment: I think the following line inside OnModelCreating is causing the issue "modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("LibraryUser");". Try removing it because you are using LibraryUser.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto - YES! I think we hit it at the same time.. I was just coming to update you :D would you like to add that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Great! I'm glad that we could solve it. Ok, I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There conflicting line is located inside the OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LibraryUser>().ToTable("LibraryUser");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("LibraryUser"); // <-- this one
```

Because you are using the LibraryUser as a derived class from IdentityUser, you don't need to explicitly map IdentityUser to a table. Doing it messes up with how the primary and foreign keys are generated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Claims to put in database(you did in `AddClaim()`) and to make contain in token are different. You have to put claim data manually in inherited `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class, which ASP.NET gives default ApplicatoinOAuthProvider.cs in Provider folder or whatever oauth provider you made.

At there, overriden `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()` method did `AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);` in order to put claims in token.

Then, Windows Identity will read the claims from token you put.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (var userManager = _container.GetInstance<ApplicationUserManager>())
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user);

            // Below line adds additional claims in token.
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }


    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(AspNetUser user)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Id", user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
            {"http://axschema.org/namePerson", user.Nickname,},
            {"http://axschema.org/contact/email", user.Email,},
        };

        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Youngjae, I have edited my question to show the lines from my app that you discuss here.. I suppose what im not understanding is when/where/how those claims I added to the DB for this user.. are added to the token??

Comment: @LukeKentwell // that's quizzy and I'm also in trouble (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/25136027/361100 ). The only way is to refresh it but what I know is, we cannot refresh token until the token is invalidated(expired or somewhat revoked) or regenerated by user. Manually revoking token is not applicable in Windows Identity Foundation solely, but IdentityServer v3 project can make revoke it developers said.

Comment: For more information, see BrockAllen (Identity Server dev) answer: http://forums.asp.net/t/2023270.aspx?How+to+revoke+invalidate+Bearer+token+in+Asp+Net+WebApi+2+2+when+using+OAuth and additional information at here to refresh token. http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/