# Owin identity framework returns no claims when tables are renamed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

If I create a brand new MVC website in Visual Studio (asp.net 4.6.1), I am able to add/retrieve claims by doing the following in the Register() method of the AccountController class:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    var addClaimResult = UserManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("test", "test"));
    var claims= UserManager.GetClaims(user.Id); 

    //claims.Count == 1
}
```

If I rename the tables by overriding OnModelCreating as follows, then claims.Count above is 0. In other words, once I rename the tables, I cannot get the claims from the database anymore.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    string prefix = "Identity";
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable($"{prefix}Users", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable($"{prefix}Users", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable($"{prefix}UserRoles", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable($"{prefix}UserLogins", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable($"{prefix}UserClaims", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable($"{prefix}Roles", "dbo");
}
```

The AddClaim method returns successfully, and I can confirm that 'test' is added to the table in the database. Everything else related to the identity framework still works (logins, etc), it's just that the claims added to the database are never returned. I've tried through MVC and Web API 2, I've tried at different times (ie after login, after authorizing, after multiple web method calls, whatever).

I enabled entity framework logging. AddClaim hits the database. GetClaims doesn't hit the database in either case (tables renamed or not).

Why is the claims.Count = 0?

Answer (score 0):

[ASP Identity 2 + Web API Token Auth - Persistent claims not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734523/asp-identity-2-web-api-token-auth-persistent-claims-not-loading)

Same answer as above.

modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable($"{prefix}Users", "dbo"); not needed.